# using wms and wfs with with osmdroid or any other opensource java based library

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, kml, wms

I was asked to develop an android map application which uses wms-wfs source from geoserver.

in order to be more clear I want to accomplish

1. send a wms 'getmap' request then get an image then append it to the mapview as an overlay.
2. when wms overlay is touched(I will take touch point's x and y values) then send a 'getfeatureinfo' request including x and y to geoserver. Geoserver will look for the geometry whose coordinate corresponds to users' touch point. if there is a geometry, geoserver will send an xml file,
3. get xml response(either kml or an xml file I'm not sure about difference) then parse this xml file to get geometry's info which is at touch point. This xml may include this info

   - geographical points (this may be a point, a road, a poligone or a multipoligone...
   - geometry's display name(city name, raod name etc)
4. create appropriate geometry depending on this xml file.

   I know I need too much help. Thanks for any reply(I explain may way for anyone new in this area maybe the question can help)

By the way I have found some resources during this time. They're said to support wms, wfs services. Let me share them:

- [nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/) which is a commercial library
- [openscales](http://openscales.org/) which is an actionscript based library
- mapsforge about which I couldn't find any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for above, but it would help if you could show some of what you have tried / used, and exactly where you are having problems. To be helpful, here are the results of my googling:

1. Look here for a simple KML Parser example for Android: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-sdk/com/android/ddmuilib/location/KmlParser.java.htm
2. Here is an example of XML parsing on Android: http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/07/19/android-simplified-source-code-for-parsing-and-working-with-xml-data-and-web-services-in-android/
3. Here is a tutorial on mapview on Android: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Please update you question with more details and I expect you will get a better response.

Comment: Thanks for your recomendation, I will try these combinations

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Esri's ArcGIS SDK for Android. It has support for rendering WMS layers (not sure how it stands with more advanced stuff though):

[ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-android/sdk)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had looked up for pricing. Is this library require to pay money to esri?

Comment: AFAIK, using SDK it's for free.